# Slumdog millionaire (7)

Tags: knowledge, family

My Indian friend Jamal recently participated in the well-known TV quiz
show ***[Who wants to be a millionaire?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Wants_to_Be_a_Millionaire)***. You might have heard or read about Jamal's spectacular success; the media reported on it extensively.

Here is what Jamal told us about his 4.000 Euro question:

> I knew that A, B, and C were all relatives. Answer D seemed to be the throw-away answer since he was human instead and he was voiced by Mr. Top 40 himself. Answers A and B reminded me of two characters from "Through the Looking-Glass", and they even came in the right order; however, I was pretty sure that they were his cousins instead.  So, I chose the character who many people have said screwed up the show. Good choice! I had reached the 8.000 Euro question!

***What was the 4.000 Euro question?

What were the four possible answers A, B, C, D?***

Comment: This is a pretty interesting concept for some questions!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Which one of these is Scooby-Doo's nephew?
>
> A. Scooby-Dee
>   B. Scooby-Dum
>   C. Scrappy-Doo
>   D. Shaggy

"Scooby Dee" and "Scooby Dum" sound like "Tweedle Dee" and "Tweedle Dum" from "Through the Looking Glass", and they were cousins. Scrappy Doo was a third cousin (and did screw up the show). Shaggy (Rogers?) was voiced by Casey Kasem, voice of America's Top 40 radio show.